# Creating a server with Hapi.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I'm going through a tutorial on Hapi.js. In the code below,

```
// Start the server
server.start((err) => {

if (err) {
    throw err;
}
console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
});
```

What is the syntax used in `(err) =>`. Is it a function declaration? I can't find this operator in Javascript syntax anywhere. Appreciate any clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the arrow function expression. You can read about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know what to search for.

Comment: It's unfortunate that a basic tutorial throws newfangled ES6 notation at newbies.  IMO, better to stick to ES5 for a while longer.

Comment: @user949300 I'm not sure that's the best approach. ES6 will be the norm in not too long, and it's additions lead to less error prone code. The node website has also opted for ES6 too: https://nodejs.org/en/about/. I think we need to start create JS tutorials that ignore old syntax like using `var`. IMO.